# Python threading with filehandling

Tags: python

Hello I have a program that looks through a range of data and finds anomalies in that data. To make my program faster I incorporated the use of threads (66 in total) now when my program finds the anomalies I would want it to write it to a file but however when i try to write to the file from within multiple threads it wont write.

```
class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,arg1,arg2,lock,output):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.lock = lock
        self.file = output
    def run(self):
        # print "Starting " + self.name
        main(self.arg1,self.arg2,self.lock,self.file)
        # print "Exiting " + self.name

def main(START_IP,END_IP,lock,File):
 # store found DNS servers
     foundDNS=[]

 # scan all the ip addresses in the range
     for i0 in range(START_IP[0], END_IP[0]+1):
        for i1 in range(START_IP[1], END_IP[1]+1):
           for i2 in range(START_IP[2], END_IP[2]+1):
               for i3 in range(START_IP[3], END_IP[3]+1):
                # build ip addres
                   ipaddr=str(i0)+"."+str(i1)+"."+str(i2)+"."+str(i3)

                   print "Scanning "+ipaddr+"...",
                   # scan address
                   ret=ScanDNS(ipaddr, 10)

              if ret==True:
                foundDNS.append(ipaddr)
                print "Found!"
                lock.acquire()
                File.write(ipaddr)
                File.write("\n")
                File.flush()
                lock.release()

            else:
                print 
file = open("file.txt","wb")
lock = threading.Lock() 
thread1 = myThread(START_IP,END_IP,lock,)
thread1.start()
```

This uses my exact same MyThread class just with the required arguments for main to manipulate the data. If I run my code for about a minute as its scanning over DNS servers I should get maybe 20-30 DNS servers saved into a file but I generally get this:

*FILE.TXT*

```
2.2.1.2
8.8.8.8
31.40.40
31.31.40.40
31.31.41.41
```

I know for a fact (because I watched the scanning output) and that it hardly writes all of them. So why is some writing and some not?

Comment: Probably a copy/paste issue, but the indentation of the if/else block is messy.

Comment: Which OS are you running this on?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your code is not working, but I can hazard a guess that it is due to race conditions.  Hopefully someone knowledgeable can answer that part of your question.

However, I've encountered a similar problem before, and I solved it by moving the file writing code to a single output thread.  This thread read from a synchronized [queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) to which other threads pushed data to be written.

Also, if you happen to be working on a machine with multiple cores, then it's better to use [multiprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of [threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).  The latter only runs threads on a single core, while the former does not have this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

instead of providing file - provide Queue. Spawn new thread to read from Queue and file write. Or Use Locks everywhere in print too because some treads can be deadlocked.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid potential error or misuse for access file from multi-threads, you can try using `logging` to write down your result.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
file_handler = logging.FileHandler()
formatter = #your formmat
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [the documentation for File Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=file%20flush#file.flush):

`File.flush()` is not enough to ensure that your data is written on disk, add
`os.fsync(File.fileno())` just after to make it happens.